# Two ways of calling coroutines nestedly?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

Imagine you have those coroutines

```
awaitable<void> a() {
    ...
}
awaitable<void> b() {
    co_await a();
}
awaitable<void> c() {
    co_await b();
}
awaitable<void> d() {
    co_await c();
}

int main() {
    io_context ctx;
    co_spawn(ctx, d(), detached);
    ctx.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Can I rewrite `b`, `c`, `d` as:

```
awaitable<void> b() {
    return a();
}
awaitable<void> c() {
    return b();
}
awaitable<void> d() {
    return c();
}
```

?

As you can see, coroutine `a` does not return anything, so we can simply pass the awaitable object outside by `return a()`

Will you choose the first form or the second form?

Comment: These two are not equivalent. Your second version is simply synchronous nested calls. The `co_await` operator is more complicated, for example after `co_await` the code may resume on a different thread. So it depends on the context. Your example is trivial, it seriously doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

If `awaitable<void>` supports `co_await`ing other `awaitable<void>` (not all coroutine return objects do support `co_await`ing something) than those two examples should probably conceptually do the same thing when we assume sane implementation of some "awaitable".

> Will you choose the first form or the second form?

When they are conceptually equivalent (do the same thing) I would prefer second form (`return a();`) as it put less stress on the compiler and does not depend on optimizations from the compiler to be performant.

As your example contains multiple layers of awaitable-returning function (which is odd) I take a liberty to talk about why this two forms are not equivalent in the general sense.

Lets pick a `future` (result of asynchronous operation) as an example of some `awaitable`.

Then given

```
future<> a() {
    ...
}

future<> b1() {
    co_await a();
}
future<> b2() {
    return a();
}
```

`b1` and `b2` should be indistinguishable to the caller, but in the general sense `co_await a()` and `return a()` is not equivalent. As `b1` contains `co_await` `b1` is implemented as a coroutine and `b2` is a "plain" function (as it does not contain `co_await/co_return/co_yield).

The difference between them becomes apparent if we add other code inside those functions.

```
future<> c1() {
    // this is a coroutine (as there is co_await/co_return/co_yield inside)
    // so execution of c1 body could be suspended here (see initial_suspend, eager and lazy
    // coroutines)
    // and next line would be executed only after resuming this coroutine once (this could
    // happen on another thread or delayed in the same thread)
    std::cout << "begin";
    co_await a(); // this co_await could suspend execution too
    // so next line could be executed only after resuming this coroutine once more (again
    // it could be executed on another thread or delayed)
    // and here (after `co_await`ing a future) future would be already completed and its
    // result would be available (for example some side effect would be already completed)
    std::cout << "after"; 
}

future<> c2() {
    // this is a "plain" function
    // next line is always executed immediately inside c2 body, before returning from c2
    std::cout << "begin";
    return a();
    // resulting future could be still incomplete even long after returning from c2
}

future<> d1() {
    // this is a coroutine as there are co_await/co_return/co_yield inside
    
    co_await a(); // this starts and awaits result of a first a()
    co_await a(); // this starts and awaits result of a second a()
    // this was sequential execution of two a's
}

future<> d2() {
    // this is a "plain" function
    
    a(); 
    return a();
    // if future is eager (starts its execution even without being co_await'ed) that
    // was a parallel execution of two a()
    // if future is lazy (delays its execution until co_await'ed) that was
    // a "future"-leak - one of the invocations of a() was discarded without executing it
    
    // whether future is earger or lazy depends on the implementation of the future<>
    // promise type (see initial_suspend)
}
```

Comment: Oh you are right, but I can still add `d()` to the executor when it is written in the `return` form. When `d` is a coroutine, calling `d()` will get its promise object instead of executing it. When `d` is a function, calling `d()` will recursively call `c`, `b` and `a`, but `a` is a coroutine, its promise object gets directly passed through the calling chain and returned to the executor

Comment: _When d is a coroutine, calling d() will get its promise object instead of executing it_ @aleck099 I think you are mistaken. Could you show an implementation of `awaitable<void>`  that you are thinking of? Also promise objects are stored inside the coroutine frame and not being returned. The result of `promise.get_return_object()` ("return object" of the promise) is returned from the coroutine function call.

Comment: It is `boost::asio::awaitable`. Also, if `initial_suspend` returns `suspend_always`, doesn't it mean that the coroutine gets suspended as soon as we call it? About the return value of `d()` and `co_await d()`, I think `d()` returns the promise while `co_await d()` returns the actual value (`co_return`ed by `d`)